# javascript recursion basics

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to learn the concept of recursion, I normally use loops where possible. Can anyone please explain what is happening in this code given the array of numbers.

```
var set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function recurs(array) {

if (array.length === 0) {
    return 0;
}
else {
    return array.shift() + recurs(array);
}
  }
    console.log(recurs(set));
```

I understand the if statement it's basically giving the recursion a chance to end. But I'm confused with what exactly is going on in the else statement, I understand the .shift() function removes the first index of the array but then what exactly? I have run through a debugger and still can't quite get my head around it. The correct answer is 15 I just need to fully understand why. If anyone could break it down for me it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`array.shift()` removes the first element of the array, and also **returns** that element. So that value then gets added to the result of performing the recursive call. The recursive call then does the same thing with the remaining values of the array. So we start with

```
recurse([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

which does:

```
1 + recurse([2, 3, 4, 5])
```

which turns into

```
1 + 2 + recurse([3, 4, 5])
```

and eventually into:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + recurse([])
```

In this last case, the `if` block just returns `0`, so the final result is:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 0
```

Comment: much better visual, kudos.

Answer (score 1):

Break it down:

```
array:         return value (usually shift() + recurs():
[1,2,3,4,5]    1 + (next line, this is the recursive call)
[2,3,4,5]      2                   + "
[3,4,5]        3                   + "
[4,5]          4                   + "
[5]            5                   + "
[]             0 (array.Length==0)
```

So, basically the result becomes: (1 + (2 + (3 + (4 + (5 + (0))))))
Where each `()` is an entry into the `resurs` function.

I'd recommend adding `console.log` inside the function to see what's incoming, and also store the return value of `recurs` before returning it and `.log`ging that as well (to give you a better visual).

Answer (score 1):

The shift method removes the element at the zeroeth index and shifts the values at consecutive indexes down, then returns the removed value. If the length property is 0, undefined is returned.

in your example if the length of the array > 0 you are keeping the first element and then calling the method again with rest of array. Break down of your code looks like this

```
recurs([1,2,3,4,5])
1 + recurs([2,3,4,5])
1 + 2 + recurs ([3,4,5])
1 + 2 + 3 + recurs([4,5])
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + recurs ([5])
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + recurs([])
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 0
15 (results)
```

Answer (score 1):

The MDN exlanation on [Array.prototype.shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) you can find here. When you remove the first element from the array, it also returns the removed value (or undefined), and it changes the length of the array

In a sense, your function would be very similar to

```
function sumElements(array) {
   if (!array || array.length === 0) {
       return 0; // full sum
   }
   // get the first value
   var firstValue = array[0];
   // remove it from the array
   array.splice(0, 1);
   return firstValue + sumElements(array); // get the next first value, which happens until the arrays length === 0
}
```

Your code a bit more clearly written (you don't really need the else there), would be

```
function recurse(array) {
    if (!array) || array.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    var value = array.shift();
    return value + recurse(array);
}
```

You of course don't need to get the value like this, it would simply show you in the debugger that

- value got assigned with the previous first index of the array
- array.length has changed and you are now using the changed array in your recursion

An interesting point to note, is that the array you are sending to your recurse value, will be an empty array after the recursion function, but i'm sure that might be fine in your case (cannot judge it) ;)